# Upgrade PostGIS from 2.3.3 to latest version

Tags: postgis, installation

Current I have the following Version of PostGIS

```
POSTGIS="2.3.3 r15473" 
GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" 
PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" 
GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" 
LIBXML="2.9.4" 
LIBJSON="0.12.1" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

And my Postgresql version is

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1)
```

I want to upgrade from this version to the latest 2.5.0 version.

How can I update this?

This upgrade will take place in a production server.

Comment: so you don't test? in a dev/lab environment? .. that's risky business.

Comment: I will test on dev/lab environment....but I wanted to focus my urgency

Comment: What is wrong with the documentation?:  https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#upgrading